# Excel (CSV) - transform header data to rows mapping with repeating rows

Tags: python, excel, header, rows, transformation

I have Excel based data set which needs transformation. I would request a Python based solution as I am learning Python and can read/modify the code thereafter. I am OK with either an Excel or CSV based input/output.

**This is what my data looks like**

**Channel**      **Condition**      **Value1**    **Value2**    **Value3** *(Header)*
Channel A    Condition B    Live      Live      Pilot

Channel A    Condition B    Live      Pilot     Live

Channel B    Condition C    Pilot     Pilot     Pilot

Channel C    Condition D    Live      Live      Live

**This is the output I want:**

**Channel**      **Condition**      **Value(all)** **Status** *(Header. I am OK if this does not show up on output)*

Channel A    Condition B    Value1     Live

Channel A    Condition B    Value2     Live

Channel A    Condition B    Value 3    Pilot

Channel A    Condition B    Value 1    Live

Channel A    Condition B    Value 2    Pilot

Channel A    Condition B    Value 3    Live...

Basically it is a repetition of the Channel and Condition for each of the "Values" which should be fetched from Column header and the dataset it self (Live/Pilot).

I would appreciate some assistance as I have about 1000 rows of such transformation to do

Here is an Image representing what I want 
[image]

Edit 2: There's a type on the screenshot. the Last 3 rows should read Channel B, not Channel A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the xlrd module. Something like:

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(index)

column_list = range(0, sheet.ncols)

val_name = [sheet.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=i) for i in column_list]
channel = val_name.pop(0)
condition = val_name.pop(0)

print(channel, condition, "Value *", "Status")
lines = []
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    row = [sheet.cell_value(rowx=r, colx=i) for i in column_list]
    channel = row[0]
    condition = row[1]
    values = row[2:]

    lines = zip( [channel]*len(values),
                 [condition]*len(values),
                 val_name,
                 values)
    for l in lines:
        print(l)
```

Comment: Reading/writing CSV/Excel is something I can probably do , the main issue is doing the transformation from header to rows mapping. I'll try it out. thanks.

Comment: this works. brilliant. now to figuring out how to place the output back in to excel / csv. thanks guy.

Comment: So the out put for one of the row is like this "(u'Channel', u'Channel A') (u'Condition', u'Condition b') (u'Value1', u'Live') (u'Value2', u'Live') (u'Value3', u'Pilot')", I want it to be multiple rows. Meaning for each "Value, Live", the Channel and Condition field needs to repeat. 
Row 1 <Chanel A      Condition B    Value 1    Live>. Row 2 <Channel A Condition B Value2 Live>...

Comment: Try using the xlwt module to write an .xls file or the csv module to write an .csv file... You sould be able to loop through the input and add one line for each Value* column

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should to the job.

```
import csv

transformed = []
with open('excel.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in r:
        channel, condition, *vals = row
        for val in vals:
            transformed.append([channel, condition, val])

with open('transformed.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in transformed:
        w.writerow(' '.join(row))
```

Comment: I got some errors about the *val, so I changed *val to Value1, Value2, Value3 and now i get following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open('1.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: It should work now. It expects your file as excel.csv and writes to transformed.csv. Maybe you have to tinker with the csv.writer parameters to your liking...Cheers